# Fiddler Get HTTP Response

Tags: c#, .net, http, fiddler, fiddlercore

I am using Fiddler.Core to intercept HTTP Request.

Below is my code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {         
            //Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 60000);
            Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(Console_CancelKeyPress);
            FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest;
            FiddlerApplication.BeforeResponse += FiddlerApplication_BeforeResponse;
            FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete;
            FiddlerApplication.Startup(80, true, true, true);
               while (!_s_stop)
            {

            }
            Console.ReadLine();            
        }

        static void FiddlerApplication_BeforeResponse(Session oSession)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(oSession.url);
        }

        static void FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest(Session oSession)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(oSession.url);
        }

        static void FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete(Session sess)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(sess.url);
        }
```

Why before response and after session complete not called?
Is it true I use port 80?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running the `Demo\Program.cs` example that comes with the FiddlerCore package to see how it works? The infinite loop you have in your `Main()` function will peg a single-core of your CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect port 80 is already in use by IIS. You will need to turn IIS off or change the port fiddler use.